# MyGet - Double build every time with Github Hooks

Tags: github, githooks, myget

In my MyGet account, I have setup an automated build using Github Hooks. Every time I push on the master branch of my Github repo, the build on MyGet is executed twice. This bothers me because I want to use the auto-tag feature but the double build means that the tag is added twice to my git repo, and the build counter is incremented twice.

Is there any setting that I might have missed somewhere that somehow fires the Github hook event twice ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have both the MyGet service hook on your GitHub repo, as well as a manually added HTTP POST hook.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.